# A suitable product of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Has anyone ever seen the following construction in graph theory?

Consider the complete graph on $3$ vertices, say $K_3=K_3(1)$. Now pick a copy of $K_3$ for any vertex of $K_3$, $K_3^{(1)}, K_3^{(2)},K_3^{(3)}$ and arrange them in a triangle. Connect one of the vertices of $K_3^{(i)}$ to one of the vertices of $K_3^{(j)}$ in such a way to obtain the second graph, $K_3(2)$ in the following figure:

[image]
Now pick a copy of the resulting graph for any vertex of $K_3$ and repeat the procedure in such a way that one of the vertices having connectivity $2$ in the copy $i$ (they are exactly $3$) is connected to a similar vertex in the copy $j$. You'll obtain a figure similar to the third in the image, let's call it $K_3(3)$, and "in the end" some kind of *Sierpinski-like* graph will be on your sheet of paper.

My zero-th question is: how can this construction be generalized (if it can)? Fix an integer $p\ge 2$; the complete graph with $p$ vertices allows one to build the same kind of object (a connectivity argumet helps in defining without ambiguity how sides have to be connected in passing to $K_p(n)$ to $K_p(n+1)$ -notation is obvious I think), and objects similar to
[image]

My real questions:

1. Is this construction already known/studied/used? Is it useful?
2. Can one take a step futher and generalize this idea defining a suitable "product" between two graphs? The idea is: given $G,H$ graphs define $G\otimes H$ taking a copy of $G$ for any vertex of $H$, and then "connect various copies of $G$ according to the connectivity of $H$" (I'm totally aware that this is far from being well-defined: part of the question is "how can it be properly defined?"). The idea is to obtain somethng like this:

[image]

Comment: Our hope (I'm turning here a question a friend of mine posed me yesterday) is that at least in the case of $K_p(n)$ different choices lead to isomorphic graphs.

Comment: Did somebody remove the comment?

Comment: I think that for the construction of $G\otimes H$ to make sense, you need to connect every point in each copy of $H$ with every point in every other copy of $H$ such that there's an edge between the corresponding vertices in $G$. That makes the construction work for arbitrary graphs. It's not much of a generalization. But I doubt you can hope for that, at least not in purely graph-theoretical terms, as it depends on how you embed the graphs in the plane.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to define $G \otimes H$ when $G = K_p$ and each vertex of $H$ has degree at most $p$.  It's one good way to generalize your construction.

The vertex set $V(G \otimes H)$ is $V(G) \times V(H)$.  We'll define the edges $E(G \otimes H)$.  We consider that each $e \in E$ is a subset of $V$ of size 2.

For $h \in V(H)$, define $E_h(H) = \{e: h \in e\} \subseteq E(H)$.  Define $X_h = \{h\} \times E_h \subseteq V(H) \times E(H)$, and $X = \bigcup_h X_h$.  By the assumption on degrees in $H$, choose $f: X \rightarrow V(G)$ such that for each every $h$, $f \mid X_h$ is one-to-one.

Now for $\beta \in E(H)$, we can define the corresponding edge in the big graph: $\beta_G = \{(f(h, \beta), h): h \in \beta\}$.  We also want a copy of $G$ for each vertex of $H$, which is $\bigcup \{E(G) \times \{h\}: h \in V(H)\}$.  So the whole $E(G \otimes H) = (\bigcup_h E(G) \times \{h\}) \cup \{\beta_G\}_\beta$.

The choice of $f$ does not matter, because of the symmetry of each copy of $G$.  So this completes the definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the friend @tetrapharmakon was [talking about](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201753/a-suitable-product-of-graphs#comment460396_201753).

I want to give half an answer and state a more specific question.

Consider two graphs $G$ and $H$ of vertices $V(G)$ and $V(H)$. The product $G\otimes H$ we'd like to define

- must contain $|V(G)|$ copies of $V(H)$ as disjoint subgraphs;
- these subgraphs must be connected *like the vertices* of $G$ *in some way*.

I thought of a way to make the sense of "*like the vertices*" precise. To account for the ambiguity of "*in some way*" I define a family of products instead of a single one.

Given a function $\phi:V(G)\times V(G)\rightarrow V(H)$ let the product $G\otimes_\phi H$ be defined as follows. The vertices are $V(G\otimes_\phi H)=V(G)\times V(H)$. Connect two of them, say $(g,h)$ and $(g',h')$

- either if $g=g'$ with $h$ and $h'$ adjacent in $H$ *(this builds the subgraphs)*
- or if $h=\phi(g,g')$ and $h'=\phi(g',g)$ *(this connects them)*.

This definition catches the way how we want the subgraphs to be connected and relegates the ambiguity in how to do so to the choice of $\phi$, giving a family of well defined products with the properties we seek.

This may be a starting point to answer question 2. But now I want to apply question 1. to these products I just defined: are they a known/studied/useful structure?

As an example, if $\phi_1:(i,j)\mapsto j$, $\phi_2:(i,j)\mapsto(j,j)$ and $\phi_3:(i,j)\mapsto(j,(j,j))$ then $K_p\otimes_{\phi_1}K_p$, $K_p\otimes_{\phi_2}\left(K_p\otimes_{\phi_1}K_p\right)$ and $K_p\otimes_{\phi_3}\left[K_p\otimes_{\phi_2}\left(K_p\otimes_{\phi_1}K_p\right)\right]$ give the first three iterations of the gaskets we were building at the beginning. The pattern for the following iterations is quite clear.

@tomasz. I may have misunderstood you but [what you're describing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201753/a-suitable-product-of-graphs#comment460409_201753) sounds to me like the lexicographic product of two graphs. The problem is that at the very least we want the product to reproduce the gasket-like structures of the pictures above when multiplying complete graphs. The lexicographical product fails to achieve this. Unfortunately every common graph product I know of (cartesian, tensor, lexicographical, normal, co-normal and rooted) fails to do this.

@DanLitt. [The idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201753/a-suitable-product-of-graphs#comment460416_201753) seems good but it heavily relies on how we embed the graphs and on the way we measure distances. In my opinion it would be very tricky to formalize it - that is, I don't know how to do it.

@Hew Wolff. I like [the way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/201812/35679) you relied on the symmetry of the first factor to give an unambiguous definition.